# Do they use a specific organ to play baseball tunes live in the stadium?

Tags: baseball, trivia, fans

What is the organ that is used to play baseball tunes live in the stadium called? Is there a common brand or model that they prefer for that?

Comment: I doubt there is a common model, with new stadiums being built and renovated constantly. I'd assume that they each have their own organ

Comment: I bet this is also up to the player's preference, to each their own. A quick 'Organ Baseball' search on Google Images will show you how almost every stadium has its own setup. And there is not even a standard form as some use a double organ while some other use a simple one. I'm pretty sure it's really up to the player.